# How to properly stabilish a usb connection to android apk?

Tags: java, android, usb

Im trying to get a usb connected camera on my android app to work. I've follow te instructions from https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/usb/host.
However i've encountered two problems:

1. request permission system dialog is never shown. I ask for the
   permission, but it is always denied
2. the connection is always null. I can get the device info such
   as number of interfaces, endpoints, device name etc, but the
   connection is always null.

   ```
       package com.example.usbdev;
       import android.app.PendingIntent;
       import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
       import android.content.Context;
       import android.content.Intent;
       import android.content.IntentFilter;
       import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
       import android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice;
       import android.hardware.usb.UsbDeviceConnection;
       import android.hardware.usb.UsbEndpoint;
       import android.hardware.usb.UsbInterface;
       import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager;
       import android.os.Build;
       import android.os.Bundle;
       import android.view.View;
       import android.widget.Button;
       import android.widget.Toast;
       import android.widget.TextView;
       import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
       import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
       import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;


       import java.util.HashMap;


       public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
           public class UsbPermissionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
               @Override
               public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                   String action = intent.getAction();
                   textView.append("\nAction: " + action);
                   if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
                       synchronized (this) {
                           device = (UsbDevice)intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                           if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                               if(device != null){
                                   textView.append("\nPermission granted");
                               }
                           }
                           else {
                               textView.append("\nPermission denied");
                           }
                           UsbDeviceConnection connection = usbManager.openDevice(device);

                           if (connection != null) {
                               textView.append("\nconnection ok");
                           } else {
                               textView.append("\nconnection null");
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }
           }

           private TextView textView;
           private Button button;
           private UsbManager usbManager;
           private UsbDevice device;
           private PendingIntent permissionIntent;
           private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION";

           private Byte[] bytes;
           private static int TIMEOUT = 0;
           private boolean forceClaim = true;
           private final BroadcastReceiver usbReceiver = new UsbPermissionReceiver();



           @Override
           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
               textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
               button = findViewById(R.id.button);

               permissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
               IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
               if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                   registerReceiver(usbReceiver, filter, Context.RECEIVER_EXPORTED);
               }

               button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {
                       executeButton();
                   }
               });

               usbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
               HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = usbManager.getDeviceList();
               device = null;

               for (UsbDevice d : deviceList.values()) {
                   device = d;
                   break; // Exit the loop after finding the first device
               }
               if (device != null) {
                   // If a device is found, request permission for it
                   usbManager.requestPermission(device, permissionIntent);
               }

           }


           private void executeButton() {
               usbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
               HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = usbManager.getDeviceList();
               device = null;

               for (UsbDevice d : deviceList.values()) {
                   device = d;
                   break; // Exit the loop after finding the first device
               }
               if (device != null) {
                   // If a device is found, request permission for it
                   textView.append("\nDevice: "+device.getDeviceName());
                   usbManager.requestPermission(device, permissionIntent);




               } else {
                   // No USB devices connected
                   textView.append("\nNo connected devices");
               }

           }

           @Override
           public void onDestroy() {
               super.onDestroy();
               unregisterReceiver(usbReceiver);
           }
       }
   ```

My manifest:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            package="com.example.usbdev">
        
            <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" android:required="true"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USB_PERMISSION" android:required="true"/>
        
            <application
                android:allowBackup="true"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
                android:supportsRtl="true"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
                <receiver android:name=".MainActivity$UsbPermissionReceiver"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:exported="false">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.example.usbdev.USB_PERMISSION" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
                <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:exported="true">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>
            </application>
        
        
        </manifest>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Have you create an `device_filter.xml`? It is not explicitly stated but I would assume it is required. Also check this Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64751962/150978

Comment: @robert yes. I've followed the Q&A and I'm still getting null connection. Also, the BroadcastReceiver is never achieved

Comment: Have you tested if the app still works if you set the uses-feature android.hardware.usb.host in manifest to `android:required="true"` just to make sure the used phone has full USB OTG support?

Comment: @robert yes. the app still works. Yes, the phone has USB OTG support

Comment: You are calling openDevice before getting the permission. This cannot work.

Comment: Also you haven't declared camera permission. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbManager#requestPermission(android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice,%20android.app.PendingIntent)